# Cannot see the Master Section in Masterdetail page of Xamarain

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am  trying to get into Xamarain development and I am trying to do a small App which have the login screen and when the user press the screen it will be navigated to a Dashboard Which is actually a Master Details Page

My master details Page is as follows

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MobArt.View"
             x:Class="MobArt.View.MasterFrontPage">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Tittle="Menu">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <Button Text="WF"></Button>
                <Button Text="FW"></Button>
                <Button Text="RO Out"></Button>
                <Button Text="RO IN"></Button>
                <Button Text="Loan Out"></Button>
                <Button Text="Loan IN"></Button>
            </StackLayout>

        </ContentPage>

    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>


            <local:RollScan></local:RollScan>


    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

And Codebehind is just constructor

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MasterFrontPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MasterFrontPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And in LoginButtonclick I tried to navigate using below cODE

```
async void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var Username = usernameEntry.Text;
            var Password = passwordEntry.Text;

            UserServices usrserv = new UserServices();

            User usr = await usrserv.GetSelecteduserdataASync(Username, Password);

            if(usr.User_PK!=0&& usr.UserLoc_PK!=0)
            {                
                MasterDetailPage fpm = new  MasterFrontPage(); 
                Application.Current.MainPage = fpm;
            }
        }
```

Iam able to See the Details Section in my Page.But cannot see the Menu(Master section) when I tried for Android. Can Anyone suggest what I am missing

Comment: Not sure if this as something to do with your problem, but you have a typo in the Title attribute of ContentPage...

Comment: Than bro...fixed it ..it was not that tittle issue....got answer from elvis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am able to See the Details Section in my Page.But cannot see the Menu(Master section) when I tried for Android. Can Anyone suggest what I am missing

The Menu(Master Section) is still there, but is hidden. You can get it by swipping from the left:

[image]

But it is highly recommended using `NavigationPage` as the details Page:`enter code here`

```
...
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:RollScan />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
...
```

Thus, you will have a toggle button for your menu:

[image]